# Octave equivalent of "hold all"

Tags: octave

There is a nice command in Matlab called `hold all`, which causes subsequent plot commands to add to the current plot, using subsequent colours from the current colourmap.

But Octave says:

```
o.exe:248> hold all
error: hold: invalid hold state
error: called from:
error:   C:\Programs\Octave\324_gcc440\share\octave\3.2.4\m\plot\hold.m at line 70, column 2
```

I've been using `hold on`, but all the lines a blue and similar, and I'm finding I'm spending too much brainpower trying to figure out which is which, rather than focus on understanding the pattern.

I'm looking for a solution that I can just type in, would rather not modify Octave's code or add scripts, for all the obvious reasons. Automatic colourmap rotation ought to have been the default behaviour, so maybe I'm missing something obvious...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The option `hold all` already exists in Octave. The problem is that you're using a *very* old version of Octave. The current version is 3.6.4.

Comment: Haha, that's right! It turns out I actually installed the up-to-date version recently, but the link in the Start menu kept taking me to the old one.